# Java generate random int from timestamp

Tags: java, python, timestamp

I am trying to generate a random int from timestamp, but below java code gives output in following format.

```
java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

Output :

> 2010-03-08 14:59:30.252

Any java equivalent for python `print time.time()` which gives output like `1472916832.39`

Comment: Do you mean `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: Your question is confusing and has nothing to do with java. Please delete the java parts and ask specific for python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To print the number of milliseconds from epoch to the Date object use
`System.out.println(Long.toString(new Date().getTime()));`.

Otherwise if you just want the current count of milliseconds or nanoseconds since epoch, you have a couple options:

- `System.currentTimeMillis()`
- `System.nanoTime()`

both of which return a long.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
System. currentTimeMillis() or  System.nanoTime()